# How can i add seconds in a date time picker in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want that when you press a button, it adds 30 seconds to the date timer picker. but what happens to me is that they do not add up.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double seg;

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dateTimePicker1.Value = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(seg);    
    }
    private void s30_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seg = 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: *they do not add*  ... yes, it does ... default double is 0 ... it adds 0 second at form load

Comment: no, it does not work

Comment: It works as intended ... you add 0 at form load event

Comment: The botton click doesn't load the form again, so all it does is change the value of `seg` from 0 (which is the default value of `double`) to 30...

Comment: You are setting this value only on `Form1_Load` event. That gets triggert only, when (who guessed it...) your form loads initially.
Your `s30_Click` event on the other heand just sets a local variable to a value, that is not related to your form or DT-picker.

Comment: Yeah, your edit does that.

Answer (score 2):

Update the control's value in the click event:

```
private void s30_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seg = 30;
    this.dateTimePicker1.Value = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(seg);
}
```

The `Form_Load` event only happens when the form is first loaded.  (Note that this is specific to Windows Forms.  In Web Forms you'll need to take this a step further and persist the value somewhere, because every post-back would load a new instance of the form and the value would start over.)

Of course, since `seg` never changes to anything but its hard-coded value, you don't really need it.  Just increment the seconds by that hard-coded value:

```
private void s30_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dateTimePicker1.Value = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(30);
}
```

Then you can remove the `seg` variable from your code entirely.